# 2 server domain failing to communicate

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

Client had a powercut a short while ago, their old domain has collapsed, and I have to admit I'm on call and a bit out of my depth. Typically all my usual backup and fall back are unavailable.

No SYSVOL or NETLOGON are showing on either DC. No replication happening. Unable to authenticate anything against the domain.

simple single forest/single domain hosted across two servers.
Functional Level : 2000

```
Server 1 : Accounts-2K  
       Windows 2000 SP4
       DNS
       DHCP
       FSMO : Domain Master
       Simple File Shares
       SQL
```

.

```
Server 2 : Barn-SRV
       Windows 2003 SBS
       Exchange
       DNS
       FSMO : RID
              Schema
              PDC
              Infrastructure
       Simple File Shares
       SQL
```

The current situation.

I have been attempting to demote Server 1, in the hope that this would remove the outstanding issues I have with replication.

Neither server can replicate in either direction.

Server 1
File Replication logs are showing : http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=13559&eventno=657&source=NtFrs&phase=1

DNS logs are showing
http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=1004&source=dns

**The reverse lookup zone for the primary (and only) subnet is showing error and can't be displayed**

Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXKjJ.png

This suggests a DNS issue, but I'm not sure if that s the cause or the symptom. Can I try reinstalling DNS?

I can ping the other server from this one, ping to **domain.local** resolves correctly to the other DC.

Server 2
Logs are showing http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=13508&eventno=349&source=ntfrs&phase=1

which looks promising to me. Surely it just needs to complete that action and it will bring up the domain?

DNS is showing issues enumerating from the other DC, unexpectedly at the moment.

Everything pings from this server as expected.Anyone got any ideas? Everyone will be turning up for work soon and I'd like them to be able to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: STOP MESSING AROUND. Call an expert - be it someone local that can help you out, or pay to open a ticket with Microsoft support. By mucking about blindly, you're only going to make the problem worse.

Comment: sounds like your DNS server configuration is all out of whack.  Not something that can be "reinstalled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there in the end :

- powered off the failed DC
- using [BURFLAGS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315457) to repair domain on remaining DC

Once this finished most functions returned which took the pressure off

After that I brought the failed DC back online and forcibly demoted and removed DNS role then promoted back into the domain, allowed to rebuild then re-added DNS.

After this there were significant issues with a lack of \domain.com\NETLOGON and all GPO objects missing from the rebuilt domain, however these were recovered by running DCGPOFIX to recreate from scratch then pulling the actual GPO's back in from backup and manually recreating them (fortunatly a tiny client, they only had 6, 3 of which were no longer in use).